Angular Material Autocomplete displayWith not working in Angular 17
Does anyone know to make this work in Angular 17?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-autcomplete-displayfn?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html
It works correctly in an older Angular version but not in version 17. You can quickly test by adding this line above the existing HTML:
Control value: {{myControl.value || 'empty'}}
I’ve tried everything I can think of...

Do you have a stackblitz example of this not working in v17?

I just copied the code from the link. As mentioned before, I could not find any way to get it working. The issue is displaying the name text while maintaining id as the control value. If you add the line above to the existing HTML you will see what I mean. Thanks

I also tried changing the component to standalone and making the necessary adjustments.

I have copied your code in angular v17 and its working fine. I can see the name in dropdown text while the control value is still ID. I think that's what you were having issues with.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-17-file-upload-qa5rx4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
